# how to post an array in rest api in ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular-http

I need to send the data to rest api. the data's are in array format.

[image]

in above images the data shows as [object object]. the actual data is options which is in above.

```
public optntocart(produc_id, countid, optionsselect) {

    let optionslt = optionsselect[3];

    console.log("3: "+optionslt);
    let localaccesstoken = localStorage.getItem('token');
    let apiUrl = this.urlService.apiUrl  + 'cart';
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

    let postcredn = "access_token="+localaccesstoken+"&product_id="+produc_id+"&product_qty="+countid+"&product_option="+optionsselect;

    console.log(postcredn);

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          this.http.post(apiUrl, postcredn, options)

           .subscribe(res => {
            resolve(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res)));

           }, (err) => {
             reject(err);
           });
     });
    }
```

when i tried in post man:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
let postcredn = "access_token="+localaccesstoken+"&product_id="+produc_id+"&product_qty="+countid+"&product_option="+JSON.stringfy(optionsselect);
```

stringify **product_option** value.

Comment: data passing like this..but this is not an answer access_token=6RKAqiTHbARq8l0mYjLDp9cuYG3OMpY6yf4kTu8C&product_id=13&product_qty=4&product_option={"3":"5","4":"8"}

Comment: need to send like this:

product_option[3]=4&product_option[4]=8

Comment: it is very simple. you can directly assign that.